# Referencing the original index of an array in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Just getting into AngularJS and I have a simple question.

When there is an 'orderBy', the $index references the sorted array.  What is the simplest way to reference back to the original array index before the sort.

```
<div ng-init="names=['Jack Doe','Dave Smith','Jone Johnson','Nancy Doe','Adam Smith']">
    <h3>Presenters</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in names | orderBy:'toString()'">
                [{{$index+1}} : {{person}}]
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would have assumed that the process of ordering the array would fundamentally change it.  What do you need the original index for?

Comment: Just stretching the legs to see what is possible.  
ng-repeat creates its own scope.  The original array remains intact with the controller scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found my answer.  It's fairly simple.

Since the original array is still intact and since AngularJS allows expressions in the binding, just a simple Javascript indexOf method does the trick.

```
<li ng-repeat="person in names | orderBy:'toString()'">
    [{{(names.indexOf(person)+1)}}  :  {{person}}]
</li>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*If* the original order has business meaning you could store it in your models.

```
function Person(name, order) {
    this.name = name || '';
    this.order = order;    
}

var names = ['Jack Doe', 'Dave Smith', 'Jone Johnson', 'Nancy Doe', 'Adam Smith'];

var people = [];
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    people.push(new Person(names[i], i + 1));
}

<li ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:'name'">
    [{{person.order}} : {{person.name}}]
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks but too complicated.  Not what I was looking for.

Comment: I myself would have already had that `Person` model set up, but yes, if you don't wrap data in business models then it _is_ more complicated.